# How to loop row values of column?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Table Name - Desktop

Column - HostName

I tried this way but not working

```
Dim adapter As New MyAdapter()
Dim table As New MyTable()

adapter.Fill(table, param1, param2)

If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim s As String = table.Rows(1)("mycolumn1").ToString()
End If
```

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an exception?

Comment: this does not seem to be c#

Comment: Why you tagged it with C# ?

Comment: can you be provide more info?  are there no rows? is the table empty? are you stuck what to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All collections in .NET start with index 0 instead of 1. So this works even with one row:

```
If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   Dim s As String = table.Rows(0)("HostName").ToString()
End If
```

Note that it's better to use the typed `Field` method:

```
Dim hostName = table.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("HostName")
```

Since you have mentioned `loop`, you can use a  `For Each`:

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    Dim hostName = row.Field(Of String)("HostName")
Next
```

or with LINQ:

```
Dim allHostNames = From row in table
                   Select row.Field(Of String)("HostName")
Dim hostNamesCommaSeparated = String.Join(",", allHostNames)
```

Apart from that, since you're using a strongly typed `DateTable` and `TableAdapter`, you should also be able to access the auto generated columnes directly:

```
Dim hostName As String = table.Rows(0).HostName
```

Comment: You can go one step further and do a `.Select()` with the For Each loop.

Answer (score 1):

> How to loop row values of column with SQL Server and VB.net?

You are looking for a [`For Each`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5ebk1751.aspx) loop

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    Dim s As String = row("mycolumn1").ToString()
    '' rest of your code
Next row
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thanks for pointing that out, I guess `ToString` would do it assuming that there would be a column `myColumn1`